# How to decode dynamic nested JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have been trying to decode JSON from a backend system.

```
    {
        "Inst1": [
            {
                "symbol": "Inst1",
                "id": 357200929,
                "ltd": 20191220
            },
            {
                "symbol": " Inst1",
                "id": 357200932,
                "ltd": 20191220
            },
            {…}
        ],
        "Inst2": [
            {
                "symbol": "Inst2",
                "id": 357201388,
                "ltd": 20191220
            },
            {
                "symbol": "Inst2",
                "id": 371886725,
                "ltd": 20200320
            }
        ]
    }
```

The name as well as the number of top-level nodes (Inst1, Inst2) are variable and unknown. I believe the correct name for such nodes are “Dynamic Coding Keys” and that is why enum cannot be used.

The sub-nodes are in an array and always share the same structure. Their number are unknown and can be different for each top-node (e.g. inst1 may have 10 sub-nodes but Inst2 can have 5).

I’m struggling to find the correct way to decode/encode such reply. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Following Sh_Khan answer I tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
var json = """
{
      "Inst1": [
          {
              "symbol": "Inst1",
              "id": 357200929,
              "ltd": 20191220
          },
          {
              "symbol": " Inst1",
              "id": 357200932,
              "ltd": 20191220
          }
      ],
      "Inst2": [
          {
              "symbol": "Inst2",
              "id": 357201388,
              "ltd": 20191220
          },
          {
              "symbol": "Inst2",
              "id": 371886725,
              "ltd": 20200320
          }
      ]
  }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Inst: Codable {
  let symbol: String
  let id, ltd: Int
}

let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:[Inst]].self,from: json)
```

Comment: The JSON is invalid. You can figure out the reason instantly if you **catch** the error. Never `try?` in a `Codable` environment. In the second dictionary of `Inst1` the closing brace is missing.

Comment: Thanks Vadian. I corrected my JSON by adding the missing }. The solution recommended by Sh_Khan works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:[Inst]],from:data)


struct Inst: Codable {
  let symbol: String
  let id, ltd: Int
}
```

---

Correct json

```
    var json = """
    {
          "Inst1": [
              {
                  "symbol": "Inst1",
                  "id": 357200929,
                  "ltd": 20191220
              },
              {
                  "symbol": " Inst1",
                  "id": 357200932,
                  "ltd": 20191220
              }
          ],
          "Inst2": [
              {
                  "symbol": "Inst2",
                  "id": 357201388,
                  "ltd": 20191220
              },
              {
                  "symbol": "Inst2",
                  "id": 371886725,
                  "ltd": 20200320
              }
          ]
      }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it in a Playground without success. See my updated question.

Comment: Why are you doing try? instead of using proper error handling with do/catch? And maybe you should explain your answers better than with "You need"...

Answer (score -1):

The solution provided by Sh_Khan works.

```
let res = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:[Inst]],from:data)


struct Inst: Codable {
  let symbol: String
  let id, ltd: Int
}
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Instead mark the original answer as the good one. Don't repost.